# Custom URL in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting

I have an application running free on google app engine with url as mydomain.appspot.com. I want to change word 'appspot' in url to some other word. How can I do it. Can I do it in free accounts?

Comment: you need to buy a domain and then https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: hi  thanks for your quick response... I want to know one more thing, since my application running for free now, not even web hosting charge .. after buying a domain do I need to pay google apps for web hosting as well or only buying a domain will work..

Comment: only buying the domain will work.. as long as you are not exceeding the free quotas.. if you hit them then you will have to start paying.